# JavaScript not working in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem when I create page with the script showing `document.write("Text");` text shows up in the browser.

But I am trying to create a page that will show different colours in a sequence within a set of tiles and when I try the following code this does not work.

Please could someone help me to solve this issue the code is pasted below.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style1.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="script1.js">
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="square1id" class="box"></div>

    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div id="square2id" class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box spacing"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    background-color:#000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

h1{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
}

.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:860px;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.box{
    width:210px;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#4D4D4D;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.spacing{
    margin-right:3px;
}
```

javaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var colourinfo = {
    square1id: [
                '#000000'

                ],

    square2id: [
                '#ffffff'

                ]

};

var count = 0;

var changecol = function(){
    $.each(colourinfo, function(tileid, colarray){
    $('#'+tileid).css('background-color', colarray[count%colarray.length]);
}); 
    count++;
    };
    setInterval(changecol, 1000);
    });
```

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: is this what you want it to do?  http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/4xjh8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery code requires jQuery library linked to your webpage.

insert the following in the html part, between `<head>` and `</head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this works well, do you know how I can change this so each tile colour appears one after the other?